# Model a one to many relationship with PDAs

Tags: pda

One can find many examples online of using PDAs like a hashmap structure, i.e. for a one to one relationship. How would I go about this if each of my users can have multiple instances of the same kind of data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's up to you, of course, but the easiest way would be to include an additional numerical seed in the PDA derivation, ie:

```
Pubkey::find_program_address(&[b"one-to-many", user_pubkey, &[0]], program_id)
```

This way, you just need to derive the address, starting with `0`, and fetch the account for the resulting address. If no account is found at the address, then you can stop iterating.

You could also have an account that just does accounting at an address like:

```
Pubkey::find_program_address(&[b"accounting", user_pubkey], program_id)
```

And the account at that address could tell you how many accounts the user has, or even give you a list of seeds to use.